# How to check if request body is empty?

Tags: nginx

I tried to do it like that

```
        if ($request_uri ~ ^/page/submit$ ) {
         set $test  A; 
        }
        if ($request_body = '') {
         set $test  B;
        }
        if ($test = AB) { 
          return 403;
        }
```

But I get 200 in answer for request `curl --request POST http://example.com/page/submit`

Comment: Why would you need to do this in your web server configuration, as opposed to in your web application's code?

Comment: Because I don't want even bootstrap my web application.

Comment: `$test` variable is not set to `AB` anywhere in your code, so that condition is always false.

Comment: @Dmitro, do you really have that much empty post requests, that you need to protect your backend from them? I doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you have to append your tests so that you can test for "AB". But then, do you really need it in the server configuration?

```
set $test    "";
if ($uri ~* "^/page/submit$") {
    set $test    "A";
}

if ($request_body = '') {
    set $test    "${test}B";
}

if ($test = "AB") { 
    return       403;
}
```

Comment: I have something like ddos